# Launch multiple applications with one launcher

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, spotify

I want to launch Spotify and [spotify-notifier](http://code.google.com/p/spotify-notify/) (for sound menu integration) at the same time using the same launcher. How would I do that?

Using 11.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple solution is by altering `/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop`

Inside is a line starting with 'Exec'. Change the command used to start spotify and have it start a file instead.
Create that file (make sure it is executable) with the startup commands for spotify and spotify-notifier.